# delete directory containing too many files

Tags: sd-card, telegram

I have an app called Telegarm and it stores all its cache files in a directory inside sdcard/Android/data folder.
the problem is that there are thousand of tiny a few kilo bytes files stored in there.
while file manager app trys to read the list of files it hangs and wating a long time dosent work.
is there a way which i can delete those files fast and easy?

-p.s: my phone is not rooted.
-p.s 2:they are more than 30 000 files and more than 300 mgb!

Answer (score 2):

It could be that Telegram may misbehave when find those files missing. Anyhow. You can use command-line for the job. Setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC and execute this command

```
adb shell am force-stop org.telegram.messenger                  # this would force-stop Telegram app.
adb shell rm -rf /sdcard/Android/data/org.telegram.messenger/*  # * means everything - all files and folders. Replace it with the directory name and enclose it in "" if the files to be deleted are inside a sub-directory.
```

Alternatively, you can do it using a terminal emulator app:

1. Force-stop Telegram app from Setting → Apps → Telegram → Force stop.
2. Remove `adb shell` from the said second command and run it on terminal app.

Another alternative is to use a third-party file manager and see whether it hangs. I would suggest using even an [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app. You can use my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/124962/96277) for further info. (Tip: Use only the actions not the profiles there. Actions can be performed without a trigger/profile.)

Answer (score 0):

Native Android file manager can delete the folder and all it contents

There is no UI showing the progress, but you can check the free space that is getting expanded periodically.