# Creating a cron job on Android

Tags: automation

I want to write a bash script (similar to Linux) to run a cron job every 10 hour. The task is fairly simple, e.g. deleting files from cache folder.

According to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747880/how-to-use-crontab-in-android), I installed [busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) and [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) and phone has already been rooted. Here is what I did:

```
su -
echo "*/5 * * * * root reboot" >> /data/crontab/root
crond -b -c /data/cronjob
```

Note that for the test, I set the phone to reboot every 5 minutes to see if `crond` is properly working.

Problem is, it doesn't work! Any idea for that?

Comment: In case you are open to alternative solutions, you can consider using an [tag:automation] app to run your script after every X minutes/hours. Tasker and Automate, both can do your job easily. Related: [How to clear a Folder (e.g. Downloads) automatically on a regular/scheduled basis?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/124949)

Comment: Trying to test the recommended applications

Comment: Although it is obvious, I would still stress that you remove the sections dealing with cron job from your script, if you intend to test the script using those apps.

Comment: OK Tasker (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) did the job

Answer (score 2):

**Requirements**

1. Root access
2. Busybox : for 'crond' service
3. /system/etc/init.d folder to start 'crond' service at boot

**Creating cronjob**
Create the cronjob file in directory /data/crontab/ with filename root. Write your cronjob inside the file 'root'. Set executable permissions for the file 'root'

*Test without rebooting*
Now open any terminal emulator in device and run the following commands..

```
su -
crond -b -c /data/cronjob
```

Now the crond service will start, to check type...

```
top | grep crond
```

*Start crond at boot*

1. mount system partition in read write :

   `su -`

   `mount -o remount,rw /system`
2. Create a file 99my_daemon at /system/etc/init.d with executable permission and enter the following lines

   `crond -b -c /data/crond`
3. Close writing the /system partition

   `mount -o remount,rw /system`
4. And reboot

Example of cron filename root

```
*/15 * * * * reboot
```

Will reboot your device every 15 minutes from o'clock.

Comment: To disable read write mode need to enter `mount -o remount,ro /system` command

Comment: This solution will work only if there will be no OOM situation. If OOM killer starts working because system doesn't have free memory crond may be killed.