# Sync to dropbox and delete from android device

Tags: file-transfer, files, file-sharing

I'm using many apps that store their files locally, and they're taking too much space, I can sync their files to dropbox and delete them manually from my phone but I'm asking if I could do it automatically, two exemples :

A voice recorder that store records in /sdcard/records

A call recorder doing the same thing in /sdcards/calls

The question is how can I automatically upload a folder's content to dropbox and delete this content from my android device on certain times ?

Comment: For uploading a file to dropbox, there seems to be many examples available on [web](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=doprbox+tasker) (this one is for tasker). Same goes for automatic deletion of a file. I also have an answer for the [latter](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/124962/96277). Try few things, then let us know the result.

Answer (score 2):

There are apps like [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full), which do exactly what you want for multiple cloud storage providers.

Basically, you configure a folderpair to upload to Dropbox and delete the source files after syncing (see image).

[image: folder pair configuration]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

I'm not sure if this is a premium-only feature (I bought the pro version), but I feel like this should be in the free version as well.