# What's the "debuglogger" directory?

Tags: android-11, nokia

What is the directory "debuglogger" (/storage/emulated/0/debuglogger) for and how to completely remove it? In a week it uses almost 5% of my phone's memory. I have to delete it manually to free space, but it creates itself again in seconds.

I have a Nokia 2.3 phone with Android 11, could anyone help me to stop this?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the complete path of this "debuglogger" directory?

Comment: Hopefully helps: [How to identify the app/process which \[...\] creates files \[...\]?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214229/44325)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a rooted phone :c Nokia websites have the instructions for that, but I'm not ready to take the risk that my phone would lose some of it's functions

Comment: debuglogger is not a universal directory found in Android device's internal storage. This is most likely specific to either Nokia devices or to an app you have installed. Either way, we are in the same boat as you are. Directories in internal storage are safe to remove at anytime. If you decide to regularly cleanup this directory because of it occupying unnecessary storage space, you can refer to my answer on this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/124949/96277. Hopefully, somebody might be able to tell what this directory is all about.